# Find an input field with specific id and update attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes, tags

I have the following code that I want to change (using jquery.knob.js)

```
<div id="mylist">
<ul>
    <li class="working">
        <div style="display:inline;width:32px;height:32px;">
            <canvas width="32" height="32px"></canvas>
            <input type="text" id="o_185d57vbk1qk11b53l3s107r1rvnh">
        </div>
        <p>
            BS.txt<i>629 b</i>
        </p><span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="working">
        <div style="display:inline;width:32px;height:32px;">
            <canvas width="32" height="32px"></canvas>
            <input type="text" id="o_185d57vbk1on1lln5ngdberesi">
        </div>
        <p>
            phpbrew.txt<i>639 b</i>
        </p><span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="working">
        <div style="display:inline;width:32px;height:32px;">
            <canvas width="32" height="32px"></canvas>
            <input type="text" id="o_185d57vbk1kl6roie3d6lak15j" >
        </div>
        <p>
            blah.txt<i>2 kb</i>
        </p><span></span>
    </li>

</ul>
</div>
```

with this code :

```
function update(up, file) {
    up.context.find('input').attr('id').eq(file.id).val(progress).change();
}
```

I'm giving file.id; but it doesn't find it. Must be real stupid but I can't figure out.

Comment: You mean ,you are sending file object which has id property? Or you should send file element instead file.id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you have the id

```
$('#' + file.id).val(progress).change();
```

Comment: assuming there's only 1 instance of that ID on page

Comment: @ZathrusWriter ID means it is unique... else it is a different design problem

Comment: @ArunPJohny that's what I was thinking, but apparently there are way too many developers that do not appear to know about ID being unique, so I'm just making sure every time ;-)